# TestContainer Rabbitmq seems to release connection as soon as it is start

Tags: rabbitmq, testcontainers

I am using testcontainers in a spring boot project (version : 1.17.2) and I am trying to spin up a rabbitmq container. It seems like rabbitmq container starts up successfully, but it releases connection as soon as it is up.

I can see some error in logs but after that I can see that the test container is started. I am kind of flummoxed as to why am I seeing this error and/or if the container is started or not ?

Pasting excerpt from logs :

```
   15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: 2022-06-29 05:00:24.477316+00:00 [info] <0.703.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: 2022-06-29 05:00:24.477316+00:00 [info] <0.703.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: 2022-06-29 05:00:24.477316+00:00 [info] <0.703.0>  * rabbitmq_management
15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: 2022-06-29 05:00:24.477316+00:00 [info] <0.703.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDOUT: 2022-06-29 05:00:24.477316+00:00 [info] <0.703.0> Server startup complete; 4 plugins started.
15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000C: cancel
15:00:44.007 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: close connection IMMEDIATE
15:00:44.008 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000C: endpoint closed
15:00:44.008 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000C: discarding endpoint
15:00:44.008 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000C: releasing endpoint
15:00:44.008 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000C: connection is not kept alive
15:00:44.008 [docker-java-stream--540868428] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "end of stream"
15:00:44.008 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000C: connection released [route: {}->npipe://localhost:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2147483647; total allocated: 0 of 2147483647]
15:00:44.008 [main] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[read] I/O error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException"
15:00:44.008 [docker-java-stream--540868428] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[read] I/O error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException"
15:00:44.008 [docker-java-stream--540868428] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl$ApacheResponse - Failed to close the response
java.io.IOException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
   at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$2.read(Channels.java:240)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:81)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:149)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:261)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:147)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.close(ChunkedInputStream.java:314)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:48)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.IncomingHttpEntity.close(IncomingHttpEntity.java:111)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.close(HttpEntityWrapper.java:120)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:48)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.core5.http.message.BasicClassicHttpResponse.close(BasicClassicHttpResponse.java:93)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse.close(CloseableHttpResponse.java:200)
   at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl$ApacheResponse.close(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:256)
   at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:277)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
....................................
15:00:44.009 [main] INFO  [rabbitmq:3.9.13-management-alpine] - Container rabbitmq:3.9.13-management-alpine started in PT7.8752359S
```

Config Java :

````
public abstract class RabbitMqTestContainerConfiguration {
    
    private static final int RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PORT = 5672;

    @Container
    public static RabbitMQContainer rabbitMQContainer = new RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq:3.9.13-management-alpine")
            .withExposedPorts(RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PORT).withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3));

    public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(configurableApplicationContext,
                    "spring.rabbitmq.host=" + rabbitMQContainer.getHost(),
                    "spring.rabbitmq.port=" + rabbitMQContainer.getMappedPort(RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PORT),
                    "spring.rabbitmq.username=" + rabbitMQContainer.getAdminUsername(),
                    "spring.rabbitmq.password=" + rabbitMQContainer.getAdminPassword());
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Can you share more details, please? Like how the test looks like or a minimal sample project that reproduces the issue

Comment: thanks @EddúMeléndez. I didn't do anything funky with either the configuration or test but added both. I must say that the test passes successfully, I am just trying to find out the reason for this annoying error. Add that config and a blank SpringBootTest and you should see an error

Comment: Are you using `Testcontainers` annotation at class level? Also, withExposedPort and withStartupTimeout can be removed. If you have spring framework 5.2.5 in the classpath you can use DynamicPropertiesSource https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html Use rabbitMQContainer.getAmqpPort() instead of rabbitMQContainer.getMappedPort(RabbitMQ_DEFAULT_POST).

Comment: I can't see any errors. I see you are using `DEBUG` log level for `dockerjava` and therefore observe some implementation detail behavior, with regards to how Testcontainers probes the container for being ready. I advise to configure logging as documented: https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/logging_config/

Comment: thanks @EddúMeléndez.. I have made those changes

Comment: thanks @KevinWittek. Maybe you are right, I just need to manage the log level .. The project got scraped, but I will let you know if that solved the problem.. btw. I was able to run tests within the testcontainer even with those errors